# Comparing dates in panda module

Tags: python, pandas

Im currently using python with the pandas module to read the csv file. Right now I need some help with comparing dates. I've written a function regarding what it needs to do, I just need some help figuring out how to make the program compare the two dates to determine which one to print.

Here is what i have for my function

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df = df.sort_values(['Date'])

def average_growth():
    test_time = datetime.datetime(2019,5,2)
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if df.loc((df['Date'] < test_time)):
            print(i, row['Name'])
```

Comment: im not expert in pandas. but you dont want to datetime.date?

Comment: yeah i realized after posting, the problem is still that there is a problem comparing the dates in the file and the test_time

Answer (score 0):

To select rows with *Date* below some threshold date, and then
print their indices, run:

```
for ind, row in df[df.Date < '2019-05-02'].iterrows():
    print(ind)
```

Note that in *df.Date < '2019-05-02'* the right-hand argument can be
a **string**.

Then, if you use *iterrows*, then note that this function returns
**pairs** (index, row), so call to *row.name* is not needed, since
you already have the index value in *ind*.